# What is the difference between a SaaS and a Web-App?

Tags: web-applications, subscription, saas

I understand that all SaaS apps are web-applications, but when does a web-application become a SaaS?

Is the only difference that SaaS are managed through subscriptions?

Answer (score 0):

Saas (Software as a Service) is when you provide your application without any infrastructure requirement from the client, so the client could use your software without take care about the systems that support your software. A web app is a Saas application if the application runs in the provider infrastructure.

Comment: But aren't all web-applications also ready to use? Once one hosts an app, you don't need anything else than a browser and internet connection to access it and use it.